# UITableView not animating when sibling is a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a view controller which has a `UITableView` and a `UIPageViewController`. The `UITableView's` height is set to 0 at first. Upon clicking a button, the tableview should slide down(i.e., increase in height) and the `PageViewController` should be pushed down. I have done it like this...

```
float yPos = 61;
CGRect fr2 = self.pageController.view.frame;// UIPageViewController
CGRect fr1 = self.categoriesTable.frame; // UITableView
if (self.categoriesTable.frame.size.height == 0.0){
    fr1.size.height = 44 * self.categories.count + 20; // categories is a datasource
    yPos = yPos + 44 * self.categories.count + 20;
}else{
    fr1.size.height = 0.0;
}
fr2.origin.y = yPos;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    self.pageController.view.frame = fr2;
    self.categoriesTable.frame = fr1;
}];
```

Expected Behavior: The tableview and the `pageviewcontroller` should both slide down at the same time.

Observed Behavior: Only the `pageviewcontroller` slides down. There is no change in table view's frame. However if you execute this method once again, then the Tableview slides down.

Can anyone help me with this ? Let me know if you need more information/code.

Comment: No, I want to animate both.

Comment: mohkhan do you want animate view controller?

Comment: Try to reload data on table.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Looks like I fixed it. I decided to translate the pageviewcontroller back and forth to achieve the same effect. Below is the working code.

```
float yPos = 0;
CGRect fr2 = self.pageController.view.frame;
CGRect fr1 = self.categoriesTable.frame;
if (self.categoriesTable.frame.size.height == 0.0){
    fr1.size.height = 44 * self.categories.count + 20;
    yPos = 44 * self.categories.count + 20;
}else{
    fr1.size.height = 0.0;
}
fr2.origin.y = yPos;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    self.pageController.view.layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, yPos);
    self.categoriesTable.frame = fr1;
}];
```